# Android intent: Using ?q= in a geo: URI

Tags: android, standards, geospatial

I noticed that the Airbnb Android app sends such an intent to open a map app at a particular latitude/longitude:

```
geo:0:0?q=77.77%2C88.88
```

From my simplistic point of view, they should use the standard [Geo URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme) instead:

```
geo:77.77:88.88
```

Is that `?q=` syntax a kind of de-facto standard?
Is it a trick that solves issues that I am not aware of?
Google Maps understands that syntax, but not OsmAnd.

Comment: I hate to point you at Google, but the first result for `geo URI` answers your question and he second is an RFC about it.

Comment: @Blrfl: Neither https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme nor http://geouri.org talk about the `?q=` de-facto-standard, as far as I can tell?

Comment: @Blrfl: Neither the wikipage nor the RFC describe the `?q` parameter in this scheme.

Comment: You're both correct.  Close vote retracted.

Comment: This URI scheme is mentioned on [the official Android Developer's Common Intents Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps), possibly to add the label.